# 9th grader attempting to learn Calculus 1, 2, and 3 during the summer

Tags: calculus, self-learning

I am about to begin my extensive journey into higher and more advanced mathematics, and my starting point is learning calculus 1, 2, and 3. I prefer self-studying as opposed to a taking a class in school, (e.g. AP Calculus AB/BC) and as such, I would like to ask how you have learned Calculus 1, 2, and 3 in the past, what key concepts are necessary to understand, and what are the more difficult ideas/topics to understand in the subject. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suggest you watch calculus videos from threeblueonebrown on youtube. I am not affiliated with him in any way, but I learned a lot from his videos, even after using concepts of calculus in several (engineering) publications. But I am not sure if you should learn calculus at such an early age. I guess math instructors can comment on this.

Comment: From my experience, the hardest type of problem in Calculus 1 is optimization. Some topics you might struggle with in Calculus 2 are the applications of the Integral and parametric equations. But I don't think you will be able to learn Calculus 1, 2, and 3 all in one summer. Maybe Calc 1 and 2 are fine, while Calc 3 is much harder and it would probably require an entire summer of its own.

Comment: I agree with your standpoint on Calc 3. I should dedicate it after I've finished single-variable calc, but I now acknowledge that since Calc 3 is more difficult than the two previous courses, I shouldn't try to "cram" or rush it over the summer. Thanks for your help! Very appreciated!

Comment: The post is off-topic because it's opinion-based, but to give my thoughts: I find self-studying difficult because I prefer learning not only from a textbook but also from my friends and teachers. In your case, I think the best way to learn is by picking up a calculus textbook, opening to page 1, and reading everything. I'm not sure about any "key" concepts because every little detail matters in math, and you shouldn't worry about which topics are going to be easy and which ones would be difficult. All of it will be difficult, and that's how it should be.

Comment: My personal experience is that I learned calculus from reading the textbook, going to class, asking the professor questions, and going to office hours. IMO that's the best way to learn, especially if you constantly struggle through math problems. I tried self-learning and I'm not able to learn as much just by reading a book and watching YouTube videos by myself.

Comment: I think taking a class in a standard public high school, where there's a teacher and you have friends/acquaintances to help you out, is better than learning things on your own because you have more people to help you out (not only that, but math is more of a collaborative activity than a solo one). But as a stranger on the internet, it's not my place to tell you which type of learning you should go for. Maybe you'll find self-learning better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned calculus while in high school by reading books from the public library. It is best to sample a variety of books. You can also get a lot  from wikipedia.

You must acquire an understanding of the foundations of $\Bbb R$. It is possible to extend $\Bbb R$ to  a larger ordered field which has  "numbers" that are positive but less than any positive rational, but you cannot do standard calculus with such a field. Strangely, there was no thorough written definition of $\Bbb R$ before the 19th century, long after the development of calculus.

We show that we can extend the ordered field $\Bbb Q$ to an ordered field $\Bbb R$ which has the property that any non-empty subset with an upper (lower) bound has a least upper bound (greatest lower bound). Any such extensions of $\Bbb Q$ are isomorphic. This is why we speak of "the" reals.

$\Bbb Q$ does not have the lub/glb property. E.g. $\{ q\in\Bbb Q : q>0\land q^2>2\}$ has no $rational$ glb.

It follows that

$(1)$. If $0<r\in\Bbb R$ then there exist $q_1,q_2\in\Bbb Q$ with $0<q_1<r<q_2$.

$(2)$. If $r_1,r_2\in\Bbb R$ with $0<r_1<r_2$ then there exists $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ with $nr_1>r_2$. This is called the Archimedean property.

$(3)$. If $r_1,r_2\in\Bbb R$ with $r_1<r_2$ then there exists $q\in\Bbb Q$ and $r_3\in \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ with $r_1<q<r_2$ and $r_1<r_3<r_2$.

A basic understanding of limits (in general) and limits of sequences is necessary.
(An infinite sequence $(a_n)_n$ is any function $f$ whose domain is $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb N_0$ but we write $a_n$ for $f(n)$. But sometimes it is convenient to let the domain be some other infinite subset of $\Bbb N_0$). Different authors employ different notations for a sequence.

$(4).$ Definition. $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n  \iff \forall r>0 \,\exists n_r\in\Bbb N\,\forall n>n_r\,(|a-a_n|<r).$

Some basic tools of limits are

(5). If $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $b=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ and $r\in\Bbb R$ then $a+rb=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+rb_n)$ and $ab=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_nb_n).$ And if $b\ne 0$ then there are only    finitely many $n$ for which $b_n=0,$ and if we exclude those $n$ then we have  $a/b=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n/b_n).$

$(6).$ A useful tool that students often overlook is that $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ iff the set $\{n\in\Bbb N : |a-a_n|>r\}$ is finite whenever $r>0.$

Caution: It is often convenient to augment $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ but the usual rules of aritmetic do not apply to $\pm\infty$. For example, you may see  $\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$, which means $\forall r\in\Bbb R \,\exists n_r\in\Bbb N\,\forall n>n_r\,(a_n>r).$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I appreciate your time into help others succeed! Have a good day!

Comment: You are welcome. I have added another short paragraph after $(6).$